# NSDateFormatter not converting string for certain dates

Tags: nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get NSDate formatted date from string but there are some cases where i believe issue is due to Local user timezone, but i am not able to figure out how to fix it.

Here is the code

```
  var usrTimeZone = ltzAbbrev() // PST

    var stdat = " "
    var endat = " "

    for dats in schDate {

        stdat = "\(dats)" + "\(schStTime)" + " \(usrTimeZone)" 

        // Jul 1, 2015[12:00 PM] PST

        endat = "\(dats)" + "\(schEnTime)" + " \(usrTimeZone)" 
         // Jul 1, 2015[6:30 PM] PST

        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "EEEE MMM dd, yyyy[KK:mm a] z" 

        var StdateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(stdat)
```

**// Return Nil**

```
        println("StdateFromString = \(StdateFromString)")

        println("EndateFromString = \(EndateFromString)")       
    }
```

Please help on this as i am stuck here for couple of days.

What i want to achieve is to always get return in User System date so, that there are no translation issues.

I really don't want UTC/ GMT at all.

Thanks in Advance. 
PB

Comment: Can you give an example of a string that doesn't get converted?

Comment: Here you go,  "Wednesday  Jul 1, 2015[12:00 PM]", also i have tested quit a bit, if i pass time 12:00 PM that is when it is breaking.

Comment: Found the issue, issue is with my date format  "EEEE MMM dd, yyyy[KK:mm a] z", it should be  "EEEE MMM dd, yyyy[hh:mm a]Z"

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, issue is with my date format "EEEE MMM dd, yyyy[KK:mm a] z", it should be "EEEE MMM dd, yyyy[hh:mm a]Z"